# WatiN clear browser cache

Tags: c#, .net, caching, watin

It seems the ClearCache method doesn't quite work for IE in WatiN. at least, it doesn't work for things you've cached SINCE you've opened the instance.

Any suggestions?

I tried using ReOpen, but it errors. It also seems to do the same thing as

```
Browser.Close();
Browser = new IE();
```

Which is slow. My tests take just about twice as long to run doing it that way (which is the only current workaround for clearing the cache).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

Go through this url this will help you.

http://jawedm.blogspot.com/2009/08/working-with-cookies-and-caches-using.html

```
using(IE ie = new IE())
{
ie.ClearCache();
ie.ClearCookies();

}
```